# Is it possible to add an app to django that does not require a database

Tags: django

I have a simple script that creates a unique one time only disposable hash and I was hoping to just add it to my existing django site as this tool is for the people that use the site.

I can find nothing at all on google about this and it seems a shame to have to create a completely separate website just to provide a GUI for a simple 5 line script.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already have a site, you're saying. What prevents you from adding a view that does what you want?

Comment: Ah, you mean I can just put my script into a function based view, simple as that. Thank you, I think you've just unwittingly answered all my questions with that. Thank you.

Comment: @iFunction You shouldn't bet on dirkgroten's comment being totally devoid of purpose and intention... Also, may I kindly suggest you to the official Python tutorial, with special attention to the [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) part ? From your question, it seems this concept is not quite clear to you ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've been programming python for 10 years or so now, I get pointed to basic python often and I'm not entirely sure why, am I missing something from my questions that might be helpful for people replying?